# How to handle PAM_AUTHTOK_RECOVERY_ERR return value from pam_authenticate for valid user and password?

Tags: c++, linux, pam

I'm trying to write some server which authenticates clients using linux pam. I wrote the following class:

```
class Pam
{
public:
    Pam(const char *module, const char *username)
    {
        mConv.appdata_ptr = nullptr;
        mConv.conv = &convCallback;
        const int res = pam_start("system-auth", username, &mConv, &mPamHandle);
        if (res != PAM_SUCCESS)
            throw std::runtime_error("Failed to initialize PAM");
     }

     bool authenticate(char *passwd)
     {
         pam_response *resp = static_cast<pam_response*>(malloc(sizeof(pam_response)));
         resp->resp = passwd;
         resp->resp_retcode = 0;
         mConv.appdata_ptr = resp;
         const int res = pam_authenticate(mPamHandle, 0);
         log(res);
         return res == PAM_SUCCESS;
    }

    ~Pam()
    {
        if (mPamHandle)
            pam_end(mPamHandle, PAM_SUCCESS);
        mPamHandle = nullptr;
    }
private:
    static int convCallback (int msgId, const pam_message **msg, pam_response **resp, void *appData)
    {
        *resp = static_cast<pam_response*>(appData);
        return PAM_SUCCESS;
    }

private:
    pam_handle_t *mPamHandle = nullptr;
    pam_conv mConv;
};
```

Which then is used like:

```
Pam pam("system-auth", username);
if (pam.authenticate(passwd))
    return true;
// error handling code here
```

I discovered that pam_authenticate returns PAM_AUTHTOK_RECOVERY_ERR for valid user/password. Possible return values documented in the man page and on the linux-pam.org http://www.linux-pam.org/Linux-PAM-html/adg-interface-by-app-expected.html#adg-pam_authenticate do not contain this value at all. Documentation says that it can be returned by pam_chauthtok and this means:

> PAM_AUTHTOK_RECOVERY_ERR
>
> A module was unable to obtain the old authentication token.

And it's still unclear what does it means in case of authentication. I've tried to run code both as normal user and as root the result was the same.

Comment: You'll need to list your PAM configuration stack, but it sounds like the `pam_unix` module has the option `use_first_pass` set instead of `try_first_pass` for authenticate and it's the first entry in the PAM stack.

Comment: @Petesh /etc/pam.d/system-auth contains the following lines: `auth      required  pam_unix.so     try_first_pass nullok` and `password  required  pam_unix.so     try_first_pass nullok sha512 shadow` so looks like `try_first_pass` is default

Comment: You have verified that the conversation function is being invoked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's happening is that you're seeing `0` as the value of `appData` in `convCallback`, which is where the error is coming from - the reply data is empty, which means bad conversation, which causes the `PAM_AUTHTOK_RECOVERY_ERR` return value. This is based on reading the `support.c` file in the current code for the PAM-Linux source code.

Ok, couple of issues.

1. You can't reassign the conversation appdata_ptr value after initialization - the value of the pointer should be considered a constant after the invocation of `pam_start`. You should pass in a value there that will never change. If you checked the conversation function you would have noticed that the value of `appData` is `0`.
2. You *must* assume that the value being put into the reply is owned by the calling routine - i.e. you'll have to strdup the password string (with all the evil that is connected to that).

With both of these in mind, I slightly altered your code to the following, which should address your problems (again, this is simplified code):

```
class Pam
{
public:
    Pam(const char *module, const char *username)
    {
        mConv.appdata_ptr = (void *)(this);
        mConv.conv = &convCallback;
        const int res = pam_start(module, username, &mConv, &mPamHandle);
        if (res != PAM_SUCCESS)
            throw std::runtime_error("Failed to initialize PAM");
     }

     bool authenticate(char *passwd)
     {
         mPassword = passwd;
         const int res = pam_authenticate(mPamHandle, 0);
         log(res);
         return res == PAM_SUCCESS;
    }

    ~Pam()
    {
        if (mPamHandle)
            pam_end(mPamHandle, PAM_SUCCESS);
        mPamHandle = 0;
    }
private:
    static int convCallback (int msgId, const pam_message **msg, pam_response **resp, void *appData)
    {
        Pam *me = static_cast<Pam *>(appData);
        pam_response *reply = static_cast<pam_response *>(calloc(1, sizeof(pam_response)));
        reply->resp = strdup(me->mPassword);
        reply->resp_retcode = 0;
        *resp = reply;
        return PAM_SUCCESS;
    }

private:
    pam_handle_t *mPamHandle = 0;
    pam_conv mConv;
    const char *mPassword = 0;
};
```